# Can't figure out continuous loop?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Basically whats going on is that I'm getting the geolocation data of a viewer and creating a textfield to display this data (city,state).  After the data is pulled the text is measured to fit in the textbox and if the length of the city is too long, the text is adjusted in size to fill the textfield.

When I trace the end result of the final text size, I keep getting the (same) trace result outputted infinitely.

```
// Sets text size to fit the largest it can in a specified textfield w/h
TextField.prototype.shrinkToFit = function(iMinFontSize){

    var oFormat = this.getTextFormat();
    var iSize = oFormat.size;

    /* add an extra few pixels to text height to be sure (there seem to be some inherent margins)*/
    while(this.textHeight > this._height || this.textWidth + oFormat.leftMargin + oFormat.rightMargin + 4 > this._width){

        //Decrease fontsize on TextFormat and apply it to TextField again
        oFormat.size = --iSize;
        this.setTextFormat(oFormat);

        // break the loop if we've reached a specified minimum font size
        if(iMinFontSize != null && iSize == iMinFontSize) {
            break;
        }
    }
return iSize;
};

// Geolocation
var info_xml = new XML();
info_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
info_xml.onData = function(raw:String)
   {
      if (raw == undefined)
         {
            this.onLoad(false);
         }
      else
         {
            // Normally onData would just do this:
            // this.parseXML(raw);
            // But we need to replace that with our own parsing:

            // This is the start of the fake XML string we are going to be making up.
            var parsed:String = "<maxmind>\n";        

            // Split each of the "function" lines into it's own string.  
            var lines:Array = raw.split("\n");

            // Remove the last one because that is a blank line.
            lines.pop();

            // Replace all the Regex functions from the external class since the Regex class does not exist in AS2.
            // All we're doing is chopping out two parts of each string and creating a fake XML node.
            // We cut the function name and make that into the XML node name, then we cut the returned value and set that to be the nodes "value".
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
               {
                  parsed += "   <" + lines[i].slice(9, lines[i].indexOf("()")) + " value=\"" + lines[i].slice(lines[i].indexOf("'") + 1, lines[i].lastIndexOf("'")) + "\" />\n";
               }

            // Now parse the string into a true XML object.
            this.parseXML(parsed + "</maxmind>");

            // Back to normal loading.
            this.loaded = true;
            this.onLoad(true);
         }
   }
//If Geolocation is successful, fill the textfield with the city/state
info_xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
   {
      if (success)
       {
          //convert Geolocation xml data into an array
          var props:Array = this.firstChild.childNodes;

          //Create textfield for geolocation data
          createTextField("tf",1,141,177.30,141,45.35);
          tf.border = false;

          //Expand on several lines if needed (set to true)
          tf.multiline = false;
          tf.wordWrap = false;
          tf.autoSize = false;


          tf.setNewTextFormat(new TextFormat("_sans",40));
          tf.text += props[2].attributes.value + ", " + props[3].attributes.value;
          trace("Font size shrinked to: " + tf.shrinkToFit());

       }
      else
         {
            tf.text += "There was a problem loading the remote file.\n";         
         }
   };

info_xml.load('http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js');
```

Edit:

I originally had the following as my code, and when the same trace was initiated, the result was displayed only once.

Geolocation data on top

then the shrink loop

then this (which is an example usage that I found on a website):

```
this.createTextField("tf",10,20,20,400,150);
this.tf.border = true;

//Expand on several lines here- set to all to false to test single line only
this.tf.multiline = false;
this.tf.wordWrap = false;
this.autoSize = false;

this.tf.setNewTextFormat(new TextFormat("_sans",40));
this.tf.text = "Detroit, MI";
trace("Font size shrinked to: " + this.tf.shrinkToFit());
```

It worked, but I needed the text box to be made according to what data was pulled from the geolocation xml, so I added it in the geolocation script.

Comment: where are you tracing the end result of the final text size? (it's not in the code). Are you sure it's not just sitting in an OnFrame listener? (which just fires every time the playhead for ever and ever)

Comment: trace("Font size shrinked to: " + tf.shrinkToFit());

It's in the if statement that converts the golocation xml data into an array and then after it creates the textfield

Comment: right, so, that has nothing to do with your shrinky loop.  That's outside the shrinky loop. Why would this be called over and over? Are you loading the file over and over? I suspect you have this sitting in some frame somewhere that is just playing (that's what frames do) and so, you're seeing it x times per second (as quickly as your movie runs).  Make sure this is all done on load and unless you need this MC to be playing, call stop() in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might have created an error by calling createTextField within the scope of the XML object's load handler. If that is the case then you have some options. Either way though, you have put the textfield creation code in the wrong place, because if your XML load fails it will attempt to write to a textfield that is only created when the load succeeds.

move the textfield code into a separate function that you can call from the onLoad handler

```
function prepareTextField(strings:Array)
{
    //Create textfield for geolocation data
    createTextField("tf",1,141,177.30,141,45.35);
    tf.border = false;

    //Expand on several lines if needed (set to true)
    tf.multiline = false;
    tf.wordWrap = false;
    tf.autoSize = false;


    tf.setNewTextFormat(new TextFormat("_sans",40));
    tf.text += strings.join(", ");
    trace("Font size shrinked to: " + tf.shrinkToFit());
}

info_xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
{
    if (success) {
        //convert Geolocation xml data into an array
        var props:Array = this.firstChild.childNodes;
        prepareTextField([props[2].attributes.value,props[3].attributes.value]);
    } else {
        prepareTextField(["There was a problem loading the remote file.\n"]);         
    }
}
```

**or**

refer to the root (or whatever stage you are working on) as you create the textfield

```
info_xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
{
    //Create textfield for geolocation data
    _root.createTextField("tf",1,141,177.30,141,45.35);
    _root.tf.border = false;

    //Expand on several lines if needed (set to true)
    _root.tf.multiline = false;
    _root.tf.wordWrap = false;
    _root.tf.autoSize = false;

    _root.tf.setNewTextFormat(new TextFormat("_sans",40));

    if (success) {
        //convert Geolocation xml data into an array
        var props:Array = this.firstChild.childNodes;
        _root.tf.text += props[2].attributes.value + ", " + props[3].attributes.value;
        _root.trace("Font size shrinked to: " + tf.shrinkToFit());
    } else {
        tf.text += "There was a problem loading the remote file.\n";         
    }
}
```

Comment: _root.trace in your second code doesn't output anything. If I keep your code and remove the _root from the trace then the problem persists. lol, but I put stop(); at the end of the code and it fixed my problem.